# my signin form signs people in but doesnt show errors if invalid login attempt

Tags: php, forms, class

I have a pretty complex login script which contains 4 classes.

The login in form signs people in correctly if the user enters their details correctly but for some reason if they enter incorrect data the error messages fail to show up.

i'll post all my code and try and explain each bit as best i can. :)

ok so my login form

```
<?php
include("include/user.php");
?>
    <h2>Sign In</h2>
    <?php
    echo $user->form->num_errors; //nothing prints from this so its not getting the value or its not being set correctly?
    print_r($_SESSION['error_array']);// this prints out the errors stored in the session correctly
    if($form->num_errors > 0)
    {
        echo "<font size=\"2\" color=\"#ff0000\">".$form->num_errors." error(s) found</font>";
    }?>

    <form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <table align="left" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><span>Email: <?php echo $user->form->error("user"); ?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="user" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $user->form->value("user"); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Password: <?php echo $user->form->error("pass"); ?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $user->form->value("pass"); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="left"><div class="forgotpass">Forgot Your <a href="forgotpass.php">Password</a>?</div></td>
        <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="left"><div class="remember"><label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" <?php if($user->form->value("remember") != ""){ echo "checked"; } ?>>
        Remember me &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><br />(Untick this if on a public computer)  </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="sublogin" value="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="button orange" type="submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

the form action is set to process.php and its sublogin that has been submitted

process.php is

```
include("include/user.php");

class Process
{
public function __construct()
{
    global $user;

    /* User submitted login form */
    if(isset($_POST['sublogin']))
    {
        $this->procLogin();
    }
    /* User submitted registration form */
    else if(isset($_POST['subjoin']))
    {
        $this->procRegister();
    }
    /* User submitted forgot password form */
    else if(isset($_POST['subforgot']))
    {
        $this->procForgotPass();
    }
    /* User submitted edit account form */
    else if(isset($_POST['subedit']))
    {
        $this->procEditAccount();
    }
    /**
    * The only other reason user should be directed here
    * is if he wants to logout, which means user is
    * logged in currently.
    */
    else if($user->logged_in)
    {
        $this->procLogout();
    }
    /**
    * Should not get here, which means user is viewing this page
    * by mistake and therefore is redirected.
    */
    else
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}

/**
    * procLogin - Processes the user submitted login form, if errors
    * are found, the user is redirected to correct the information,
    * if not, the user is effectively logged in to the system.
    */
function procLogin()
{
    global $user;

    /* Login attempt */
    $retval = $user->login($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass'], isset($_POST['remember']));
    /* Login successful */
    if($retval)
    {
        $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
        $extra = 'index.php';
        header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
    }
    /* Login failed */
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
        $_SESSION['error_array'] = $user->form->getErrorArray();
        header("Location: ".$user->referrer);
    }
}

/**
    * procLogout - Simply attempts to log the user out of the system
    * given that there is no logout form to process.
    */
function procLogout()
{
    global $user;
    $retval = $user->logout();
    header("Location: ".$user->referrer);
    #header("Location: main.php");
}

/**
    * procRegister - Processes the user submitted registration form,
    * if errors are found, the user is redirected to correct the
    * information, if not, the user is effectively registered with
    * the system and an email is (optionally) sent to the newly
    * created user.
    */
function procRegister()
{
    global $form, $user;
    /* Convert username to all lowercase (by option) */
    if(ALL_LOWERCASE)
    {
        $_POST['email'] = strtolower($_POST['email']);
    }
    /* Registration attempt */
    $retval = $user->register($_POST['email'],$_POST['fname'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['pass'],$_POST['pass-confirm']);

    /* Registration Successful */
    if($retval == 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['reguname'] = $_POST['email'];
        $_SESSION['regsuccess'] = true;
        header("Location: ".$user->referrer);
    }
    /* Error found with form */
    else if($retval == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
        $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
        header("Location: ".$user->referrer);
    }
    /* Registration attempt failed */
    else if($retval == 2)
    {
        $_SESSION['reguname'] = $_POST['email'];
        $_SESSION['regsuccess'] = false;
        header("Location: ".$user->referrer);
    }
}

/**
* procForgotPass - Validates the given username then if
* everything is fine, a new password is generated and
* emailed to the address the user gave on sign up.
*/
function procForgotPass()
{
    global $mailer, $form;
    /* Username error checking */
    $subuser = $_POST['user'];
    $field = "user";  //Use field name for username
    if(!$subuser || strlen($subuser = trim($subuser)) == 0)
    {
        $form->setError($field, "* Username not entered<br>");
    }
    else
    {
        /* Make sure username is in database */
        $subuser = stripslashes($subuser);
        if(strlen($subuser) < 5 || strlen($subuser) > 30 || !eregi("^([0-9a-z])+$", $subuser) || (!$user->usernameTaken($subuser)))
        {
            $form->setError($field, "* Username does not exist<br>");
        }
    }

    /* Errors exist, have user correct them */
    if($form->num_errors > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
        $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
    }
    /* Generate new password and email it to user */
    else
    {
        /* Generate new password */
        $newpass = $user->generateRandStr(8);

        /* Get email of user */
        $usrinf = $user->getUserInfo($subuser);
        $email  = $usrinf['email'];

        /* Attempt to send the email with new password */
        if($mailer->sendNewPass($subuser,$email,$newpass))
        {
            /* Email sent, update database */
            $user->updateUserField($subuser, "password", md5($newpass));
            $_SESSION['forgotpass'] = true;
        }
        /* Email failure, do not change password */
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['forgotpass'] = false;
        }
    }

    header("Location: ".$user->referrer);
}

    /**
    * procEditAccount - Attempts to edit the user's account
    * information, including the password, which must be verified
    * before a change is made.
    */
function procEditAccount()
{
    global $form, $user;
    /* Account edit attempt */
    $retval = $user->editAccount($_POST['curpass'], $_POST['newpass'], $_POST['email']);

    /* Account edit successful */
    if($retval)
    {
        $_SESSION['useredit'] = true;
        header("Location: ".$user->referrer);
    }
    /* Error found with form */
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['value_array'] = $_POST;
        $_SESSION['error_array'] = $form->getErrorArray();
        header("Location: ".$user->referrer);
    }
}
}

/* Initialize process */
$process = new Process($user);

?>
```

as a result of sublogin submitted the above code calls the $user->login in the user class which is

```
<?php
include("include/database.php");
include("include/mailer.php");
include("include/form.php");

include("constants.php");

class user
{
var $username;     //Username given on sign-up
var $firstname;
var $lastname;
var $userid;       //Random value generated on current login
var $userlevel;    //The level to which the user pertains
var $time;         //Time user was last active (page loaded)
var $logged_in;    //True if user is logged in, false otherwise
var $userinfo = array();  //The array holding all user info
var $url;          //The page url current being viewed
var $referrer;     //Last recorded site page viewed
var $num_active_users;   //Number of active users viewing site
var $num_active_guests;  //Number of active guests viewing site
var $num_members;        //Number of signed-up users

/**
* Note: referrer should really only be considered the actual
* page referrer in process.php, any other time it may be
* inaccurate.
*/

public function __construct(db $db, Form $form)
{
    $this->database = $db;
    $this->form = $form;
    $this->time = time();
    $this->startSession();

    $this->num_members = -1;

    if(TRACK_VISITORS)
    {
        /* Calculate number of users at site */
        $this->calcNumActiveUsers();

        /* Calculate number of guests at site */
        $this->calcNumActiveGuests();
    }


}   

function startSession()
{
    session_start();   //Tell PHP to start the session

    /* Determine if user is logged in */
    $this->logged_in = $this->checkLogin();

    /**
    * Set guest value to users not logged in, and update
    * active guests table accordingly.
    */
    if(!$this->logged_in)
    {
        $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = GUEST_NAME;
        $this->userlevel = GUEST_LEVEL;
        $this->addActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $this->time);
    }
    /* Update users last active timestamp */
    else
    {
        $this->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
    }

    /* Remove inactive visitors from database */
    $this->removeInactiveUsers();
    $this->removeInactiveGuests();

    /* Set referrer page */
    if(isset($_SESSION['url']))
    {
         $this->referrer = $_SESSION['url'];
    }
    else
    {
        $this->referrer = "/";
    }
    /* Set current url */
    $this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
}

/**
* checkLogin - Checks if the user has already previously
* logged in, and a session with the user has already been
* established. Also checks to see if user has been remembered.
* If so, the database is queried to make sure of the user's 
* authenticity. Returns true if the user has logged in.
*/
function checkLogin()
{
    /* Check if user has been remembered */
    if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname']) && isset($_COOKIE['cookid']))
    {
        $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['cookname'];
        $this->userid   = $_SESSION['userid']   = $_COOKIE['cookid'];
    }

    /* Username and userid have been set and not guest */
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['username'] != GUEST_NAME)
    {
        /* Confirm that username and userid are valid */
        if($this->confirmUserID($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['userid']) != 0)
        {
            /* Variables are incorrect, user not logged in */
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['userid']);
            return false;
        }

        /* User is logged in, set class variables */
        $this->userinfo  = $this->getUserInfo($_SESSION['username']);
        $this->username  = $this->userinfo['username'];
        $this->userid    = $this->userinfo['userid'];
        $this->userlevel = $this->userinfo['userlevel'];
    $this->lastlogin = $this->userinfo['lastlogin'];
    $this->townid = $this->userinfo['placeID'];

        return true;
    }
    /* User not logged in */
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


/**
* generateRandID - Generates a string made up of randomized
* letters (lower and upper case) and digits and returns
* the md5 hash of it to be used as a userid.
*/
function generateRandID()
{
    return md5($this->generateRandStr(16));
}

/**
* generateRandStr - Generates a string made up of randomized
* letters (lower and upper case) and digits, the length
* is a specified parameter.
*/
function generateRandStr($length)
{
    $randstr = "";
    for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++)
    {
        $randnum = mt_rand(0,61);
        if($randnum < 10)
        {
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+48);
        }
        else if($randnum < 36)
        {
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+55);
        }else
        {
            $randstr .= chr($randnum+61);
        }

    }
    return $randstr;
}

/**
* login - The user has submitted his username and password
* through the login form, this function checks the authenticity
* of that information in the database and creates the session.
* Effectively logging in the user if all goes well.
*/
function login($subuser, $subpass, $subremember)
{

    /* Username error checking */
    $field = "user";  //Use field name for username
    if(!$subuser || strlen($subuser = trim($subuser)) == 0)
    {
        $this->form->setError($field, "* Username not entered");
    }
    else
    {
        /* Check if valid email address */
        $regex = "^[_+a-z0-9-]+(\.[_+a-z0-9-]+)*"
             ."@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{1,})*"
             ."\.([a-z]{2,}){1}$^";#added ^ at end!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        if(!preg_match($regex,$subuser))
        {
            $this->form->setError($field, "* Email invalid");
        }
        $subuser = stripslashes($subuser);
    }

    /* Password error checking */
    $field = "pass";  //Use field name for password
    if(!$subpass)
    {
        $this->form->setError($field, "* Password not entered");
    }

    /* Return if form errors exist */
    if($this->form->num_errors > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /* Checks that username is in database and password is correct */
    $subuser = stripslashes($subuser);
    $result = $this->confirmUserPass($subuser, md5($subpass));
    /* Check error codes */
    if($result == 1)
        {
        $field = "user";
        $this->form->setError($field, "* Username not found");
    }
    else if($result == 2)
        {
        $field = "pass";
        $this->form->setError($field, "* Invalid password");
    }

    /* Return if form errors exist */
    if($this->form->num_errors > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /* Username and password correct, register session variables */
    $this->userinfo  = $this->getUserInfo($subuser);
    $this->username  = $_SESSION['username'] = $this->userinfo['username'];
    $this->firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'] = $this->userinfo['firstname'];
    $this->userid    = $_SESSION['userid']   = $this->generateRandID();
    $this->userlevel = $this->userinfo['userlevel'];

    /* Insert userid into database and update active users table */
    $this->updateUserField($this->username, "userid", $this->userid);
    $this->addActiveUser($this->username, $this->time);
    $this->removeActiveGuest($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    /**
    * This is the cool part: the user has requested that we remember that
    * he's logged in, so we set two cookies. One to hold his username,
    * and one to hold his random value userid. It expires by the time
    * specified in constants.php. Now, next time he comes to our site, we will
    * log him in automatically, but only if he didn't log out before he left.
    */
    if($subremember)
    {
        setcookie("cookname", $this->username, time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
        setcookie("cookid",   $this->userid,   time()+COOKIE_EXPIRE, COOKIE_PATH);
    }

    /* Login completed successfully */
    return true;
}

}
$db = new db($config);
$form = new Form;
$user = new User($db, $form);
?>
```

and then there is the form class

```
class Form
{
var $values = array();  //Holds submitted form field values
var $errors = array();  //Holds submitted form error messages
var $num_errors;   //The number of errors in submitted form

/* Class constructor */
function __construct()
{
    /**
    * Get form value and error arrays, used when there
    * is an error with a user-submitted form.
    */
    if(isset($_SESSION['value_array']) && isset($_SESSION['error_array']))
    {
        $this->values = $_SESSION['value_array'];
        $this->errors = $_SESSION['error_array'];
        $this->num_errors = count($this->errors);

        unset($_SESSION['value_array']);
        unset($_SESSION['error_array']);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->num_errors = 0;
    }
}

/**
* setValue - Records the value typed into the given
* form field by the user.
*/
function setValue($field, $value)
{
    $this->values[$field] = $value;
}

/**
* setError - Records new form error given the form
* field name and the error message attached to it.
*/
function setError($field, $errmsg)
{
    $this->errors[$field] = $errmsg;
    $this->num_errors = count($this->errors);
}

/**
* value - Returns the value attached to the given
* field, if none exists, the empty string is returned.
*/
function value($field)
{
    if(array_key_exists($field,$this->values))
    {
        return htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($this->values[$field]));
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}

/**
* error - Returns the error message attached to the
* given field, if none exists, the empty string is returned.
*/
function error($field)
{
    if(array_key_exists($field,$this->errors))
    {
        return "<font size=\"2\" color=\"#ff0000\">".$this->errors[$field]."</font>";
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}

/* getErrorArray - Returns the array of error messages */
function getErrorArray()
{
    return $this->errors;
}
}
```

but for some reason like i say the form errors are not showing up? im new to oop and i realise that my code is not brilliant but im working on it :)

there is also a database class but wont post that unless you need it. have spent ages trying to get this to work but have failed missurably, any help will be greatly appreciated!

## edit

i think the problem is to do with the sessions, the reason i think this is because this part of the Form class

```
        if(isset($_SESSION['value_array']) && isset($_SESSION['error_array']))
    {
        $this->values = $_SESSION['value_array'];
        $this->errors = $_SESSION['error_array'];
        $this->num_errors = count($this->errors);

        unset($_SESSION['value_array']);
        unset($_SESSION['error_array']);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->num_errors = 0;
    }
```

always sets the num_errors to 0 the if statement always fails, if i change this->num->errors to 3 for example i get a message appear on my form saying 3 errors found. but when i print_r($session) on the signin page it has all the error data stored so there is no reason why the if should fail. any ideas??

thanks

thanks

Comment: For one thing `eregi` is deprecated. Use `preg_replace` instead.

Comment: thank you for your help and pointing that out :)

Comment: ok i have found out one error and that is with the _construct in the form class and that is it should have two underscores before the word construct which after changing now prints a value for the number of errors on the form page, however its always 0 even when there are errors? at least i am making progress lol

Comment: I didn't catch the fact that there was a missing underscore for the construct. You are indeed right and having error messages is in fact one form of progress.

Comment: Why are you still using `var` keyword? PHP5 was released in 2004th.

Comment: @fred - its something :) just need to figure out why its not returning the true number of errors instead of 0 all the time, the code checks to see if certain sessions are set  if(isset($_SESSION['value_array']) && isset($_SESSION['error_array'])) and they are, so not sure where im going wrong. more debugging and testing required lol

Comment: @teresko - the script i originally had (which i got online) was done pre php5 and im in the process of updating it, but knowing very little oop its a slow process :D

Comment: ok sorted the form errors not showing up when the user submits the an incorrect login attempt. i added $session_start() to my login.php page and it solved the problem :) thanks for all your help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of nit picking through the code i wittled the problem dowwn to the $_session varibles. after much trial and error i decided to add $session_start() to my login.php page and everything worked as expected. Not sure why the session_start() in the user class was not sufficient??? but it seems to be sorted.

now on to sorting out those var's :)